# No valida variables definidas y no vacías

Tags: php

Mi formulario envía los datos del login y quiero que valide que las variables estén definidas y que no estén vacías.

```
if (!isset($_POST['user']) || !isset($_POST['pass'])) {
*** Variables definidas y no vacías
} else {
*** ERROR
}
```

El código entra a la opción de **ERROR** si una de las variables está vacía.
Pero si tiene valores igual entra a **ERROR**.
Cuál es el problema?

Comment: el `||` (`OR`) es uno u otro, para ambos usar `&&` (`AND`), el `isset()` verifica que esté definida, para saber si está vacía usar `empty()`

Comment: lo que hago siempre es hacer la primero la variable este definida y después me fijo si esta vacía. `if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, el problema es que estás validando mal.

básicamente lo que estas diciendo en tu expresion es

si no existe post user o no existe post pass entonces las variables están definidas, lo cual no tiene sentido, lo crrecto es inidicar lo siguiente

```
//si existe post user y además existe post pass 
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
    //las variables están definidas
    echo 'Variables definidas;
} else {
    //si no, lanzo error
    echo 'error';
}
```

el otro problema es que isset sólo valida que las variables existen, por eso aunque el campo esté vació isset dará true

entonces

```
if ($_POST['user'] != '' && $_POST['pass'] != '') {
    echo 'Variables definidas y no vacías';
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

validará correctamente si post user y post pass no estén vaciós

Answer (score 1):

La condición en el if está dada vuelta, te pongo dos `if` anidados para que queden mas claro los conceptos `isset()` y `empty()`

```
if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
//*** Variables definidas (pueden estar vacias = "", = NULL)

  if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
  //*** y no vacías

  }

} else {
//*** ERROR

}
```

Comment: Funciona, pero y puedo usarlo en una sola línea? if (( isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['clave']) ) && ( !empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['clave']) ) { .. }

Comment: efectivamente, se puede armar todo en un `if` salvo que quieras permitir valores "" o filtrar espacios con `trim()` en el segundo `if` o aplicar alguna otra validación como cantidad de caracteres o fuerza de la clave, etc..

Comment: no harían falta los `(` internos pues el interprete (luego de que el compilador/optimizador  le dice que son todos `AND`) va evaluando de izquierda a derecha y deja de comparar cosas en cuanto encuentra el primer `false`

Answer (score 1):

En tu pregunta dices querer evaluar *que las variables estén definidas y no vacías*, curiosamente, lo que quieres **se parece mucho a la [definición de `empty` en el Manual de PHP:](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)**

> Determina si una variable es considerada vacía. Una variable se
>   considera vacía si **no existe** o si su **valor es igual a `FALSE`**.
>   `empty()` no genera una advertencia si la variable no existe.

De ahí podemos deducir que puedes prescindir de `isset` totalmente, usando este código:

```
if (!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    *** Variables definidas y no vacías
} else {
    *** ERROR
}
```

Quizá te preguntes si, en el caso de no estar definido uno de los índices no obtendrías algún mensaje del tipo `Undefined index` o similar. La respuesta es **no**, como dice la nota de más arriba, `empty` no genera advertencia si el índice no existe (dato comprobado).

En conclusión: Creo que en tu caso, basta con `empty`, no necesitas a <s>`isset`</s>.